# Character array on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create an array of special characters in Hebrew. I have the unicode array-and I can use `char(hex2dec())` to convert each unicode to the character. However, I would like to do the same thing using loops so that I can use it for other language scripts in the future.

```
label_uni=['05D0', '05D1', '05D2', '05D3', '05D4', '05D5', '05D6', '05D7', '05D8','05D9', '05DA', '05DB', '05DC', '05DD', '05DE', '05DF', '05E0', '05E1', '05E2', '05E3', '05E4', '05E5', '05E6', '05E7', '05E8', '05E9', '05EA']; 
n= length(label_uni); 
for i=1:n 
   label_char = char(hex2dec(label_uni)); 
end
```

I am not able to see the result-how should I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
label_uni={'05D0', '05D1'};

label_char = char(size(label_uni));
n = length(label_uni);
for i = 1 : n 
   label_char(i) = char(hex2dec(label_uni{i}));   
end

disp(label_char);
```